# Nested If-or functions with index

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, nested

I am trying to write a function that, when my index search comes up blank or returns a specific text value, the formula will print blank, else it prints what is finds in the index search.

```vb
=IF(OR((INDEX(BCP_LOG!G:G,LARGE(IF(BCP_LOG!G:G<>"",ROW(BCP_LOG!G:G)),3))="TPC"),(INDEX(BCP_LOG!G:G,LARGE(IF(BCP_LOG!G:G<>"",ROW(BCP_LOG!G:G)),3))="") ),"",INDEX(BCP_LOG!G:G,LARGE(IF(BCP_LOG!G:G<>"",ROW(BCP_LOG!G:G)),3)))
```

It is still returning a #NUM error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please format the question.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without seeing your data - how should we help you? Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Please use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to show us some sample data and the expected outcome.

Comment: Most likely you are using an older version than Office 365.  The formula will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Also `INDEX(BCP_LOG!G:G,LARGE(IF(BCP_LOG!G:G<>"",ROW(BCP_LOG!G:G)),3))=""` is not needed as the `""` are filtered out of the choices already with `BCP_LOG!G:G<>""`

Comment: If there are no blanks between and you just want the value 3 rows up from the bottom, might I suggest: `IF(INDEX(BCP_LOG!G:G,MATCH("zzzz",BCP_LOG!G:G)-2)="TPC","",INDEX(BCP_LOG!G:G,MATCH("zzzz",BCP_LOG!G:G)-2))`  Which does NOT need the Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: And have you tried IFERROR(your_function,"") ?